# Red, Green, Blue Layer in CuC Generals

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals, command-and-conquer-zero-hour

I got CnC Generals (first decade) running on Windows XP running in Virtual Box. The only thing that is quite annoying is a red, green, or blue transparent layer that gets active when some Chinese, gba or usa troop is anywhere on the visible part of screen. Is that something that is caused by a modification of tfd-103-rev4 ? Can it be disabled by configuration by some magic setting in options.ini or gamedata.ini?

If there is no troop on the current selected part of map the annoying layer disappears.

Used configuration:

- Windows XP SP3
- Virtual Box 5.2.44 with 3D acceleration activated

  - 5.2.44 seems to be the last Version with 3d acceleration driver for xp
  - HyperV potetialy stopps this old verison of Virtual Box it can be disabled using

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

- [tfd-103-rev4](https://cncnz.com/hosted-projects/command-patch/the-first-decade-unofficial-patch/)
- Played around with gentool (without any success)

[image]

The same behavior appears with Zero Hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annoying color layer went away after setting "BuildingOcclusion" in options.ini to "no". That is the config key used by the graphic setting menu for the checkbox "Behind Buildings".

That options.ini is a confing that works flawless with a XP SP3 in Virtual Box:

```
AntiAliasing = 5
BuildingOcclusion = no
CampaignDifficulty = 0
DrawScrollAnchor = 
DynamicLOD = no
ExtraAnimations = yes
GameSpyIPAddress = 127.0.0.1
Gamma = 50
IPAddress = 127.0.0.1
IdealStaticGameLOD = High
LanguageFilter = true
MaxParticleCount = 3000
MoveScrollAnchor = 
MusicVolume = 55
Resolution = 1280 720
Retaliation = yes
SFX3DVolume = 79
SFXVolume = 71
ScrollFactor = 50
SendDelay = no
ShowSoftWaterEdge = yes
ShowTrees = yes
StaticGameLOD = Custom
TextureReduction = 0
UseAlternateMouse = no
UseCloudMap = yes
UseDoubleClickAttackMove = no
UseLightMap = yes
UseShadowDecals = yes
UseShadowVolumes = yes
VoiceVolume = 70
```